# EXC_BAD_ACCESS memory management issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access

I'm working on an iPhone/iPad application and I've got an unpleasant issue.

There is the class named `MyWebViewController` with a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* currentPage;
```

and few methods:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    ...
    [self method1:self.currentPage];
    ...
}    

- (void)method1:(NSString *)key
{
    ...
    [self method2];
    ...
}
```

During dubugging when it comes to `[self method2];` row the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception but points to `[self method1:self.currentPage];` row!

I tried to enable `NSZombie` but it didn't help.

So I'm completely confused and can't get what to do. That's why I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: One glaring issue is that you don't have a parameter defined for your method1.  Also, show code that sets the currentPage.

Comment: Can you show the error message that you say points to `[self method1:self.currentPage];` ? I think you should not rule out something wrong with `method2`. Can you show that method, also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a typo in your question, your method1 signature does not take a parameter,

```
- (void)method1
{
```

but in your code, you call the method with the parameter.

```
[self method1:self.currentPage];
```

Comment: There was so stupid error! I moved some functionality to other inner method and released the returning variable before actually returning it! So I fixed it and everything works ok now :)